# Updating a SQL database from a Datagridview data: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

I have a table with the name "TB1" in my database. I want to update my `SQL` database from a `dataGridview` control when a I change its data and click on the update `button`, but there is an Error.

The error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information. 
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatingRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatingEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, DataRow dataRow) 
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping) 
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
```

What's wrong with that?

```
> public partial class Form1 : Form
>     {
> 
>         SqlConnection con;
>         SqlDataAdapter adapt;
>         DataSet ds;
>         SqlCommandBuilder cmdbl;
> 
>         public Form1()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>      
>         }
>          private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             con = new SqlConnection();
>             con.ConnectionString= (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=H:\New\RemDaBase.mdf;Integrated
> Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
>             con.Open();
>             adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  TB1", con);
>             ds = new DataSet();
>             adapt.Fill(ds, "TB1");
>             dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
>         }
> 
>  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapt);
>                 adapt.Update(ds, "TB1");
>                 MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully");
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
> 
>             }
>         }
>     }
```

Comment: btw. Your connection seem to never be closed.

Comment: But when i close that it doesn't work too.

Comment: Closing the connection will not make it work. What's the error?

Comment: I meant there is still the previous error.

Comment: What is the previous error. "It doesn't work" is not specific enough :)

Comment: Please add the text (not an image) of the error to you question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'cannot be shown here' - I added the error to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found the solution.

It is occurred because I didn't use a `primary key` in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

         con = new SqlConnection();
         con.ConnectionString= (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=H:\New\RemDaBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
         con.Open();
         adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  TB1", con);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
         bs.DataSource = dt;
         adapt.Fill(dt);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
     }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapt);
        adapt.Update(dt);
        MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: It says updated successfully. But it doesn't update the database table.

Comment: The Same Error.